# Create a memory leak under Linux

Tags: c, shell, memory, memory-leaks, embedded-linux

I created an embedded custom Linux distribution using open embedded and i want to test the behavior of my system. My test case is to see what happens "if a user space application creates a memory Leak. "

So for test reasons , i would like to create a memory leak  using a script shell or C ?

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

This function will leak:

```
void leakingFunction()
{
    int* a = malloc(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak can easily be produced

```
void func()
{
  int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
  return;
}
```

You are not freeing the memory allocated to the pointer `ptr` and hence there is a memory leak because this allocated memory is not available for other applications and eventually if you keep doing this then you run out of memory.Like

```
while(1)
{
   int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codegolf ?

```
main(){for(;;)malloc(9999999);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## ee.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

 int main( void )
{
    int *ptr = NULL;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        ptr = (int*) malloc ( 1024 );
        sleep ( 2 );
    }
    return ( 0 );
}
```

1. gcc -o memory ee.c

## mem_leak.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " memory leak script started"
./memory
```

2. chmod 777 mem_leak.sh
3. ./mem_leak.sh

Comment: Another question please System will recover memory allocated by my programme when if i exit it before be killed by the OMM killer.  create permanent memory leaks ??

Comment: No ... once your prog get exited then all the memory allocated by your prog will be flushed out.